# Android alarmmanager killed by OS

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an android app that I wrote that uses alarmManager to run media player as an alarm.
The audio that gets played is over an hour, but at 30 minutes exactly the music stops. 
I am guessing that is because the OS is shooting the process to free memory. 
Any ideas on how I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: some code and debug/logging information would definitely NOT harm

Comment: Currently I am not using a wake lock with the alarm receiver. Maybe I should be using a wakeful broadcast receiver? https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the OS was not shooting my app.

I am using alarmmanager, and apparently that prevents android from deeming the app as unused.

Wakelock was my problem, I added a partial wakelock to the broadcast receiver and now happy days

developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html